# Beginner to creating and reading JSON objects

Tags: php, jquery, json

Using http://objectmix.com/javascript/389546-reading-json-object-jquery.html as a starting point, I have been reading lots about JSON. Unfortunately I am a total beginner and can't get my head around the basics of creating JSON objects.

I have created a PHP page called getContact.php

```
<?php
"Contact": {
    "ID" : "1",
    "Name" : "Brett Samuel"
}
?>
```

And a javascript file with the following code:

```
$.getJSON('getContacts.php', function(data) {
    var obj = (new Function("return " + data))();
    alert(data.Contact.Name)
});
```

This page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx suggests I have the basic approach correct. Can anyone tell me why this does not work? Absolutely nothing happens.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is not a programming language, and it's certainly not executable as PHP.  It's just a file format.  If you want your web server to serve up a static JSON file, just drop it in the file system as *filename*.json, without any `<?php` tags.  (Of course, as with HTML, you can also make it a `.php` file and just not have any PHP in it, other than something to set the Content-Type since the file suffix won't do it automatically. But that's wasteful.)

If you want to dynamically generate some JSON with PHP, then you have to write PHP code to print it out, e.g.:

```
<?= json_encode( array( 
      'Contact' => array('ID' => 1, 'Name' => 'Brett Samuel' ) 
    ) ); ?>
```

Also, note that a JSON document has to be a complete object; yours requires another set of curly braces around the whole thing (as output by the above snippet).

Comment: Thanks @Mark your answers are always super helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Your PHP file contains JSON, which is not valid PHP, and will therefore error.

If you're working with PHP the easiest way to build JSON is to first prepare your data as an array (associative or indexed, as required) then simply convert it via `json_encode()`. (You can also decode JSON, with the corresponding `json_decode()`.

[EDIT - in response to comment, just have a look at the PHP docs for `json_encode()` - it's very self explanatory. You take an array, pass it to `json_encode()`, and you get a JSON string.

```
$arr = array('one', 'two', 'three');
echo json_encode($arr); //JSON string
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example for this (using the intended output above)?

Comment: Thanks, but could you make the example with two contacts? I am finding it hard to follow what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use json_encode and json_decode
refer this [json php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)